# Is MFC CString a wide char string

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I'm working on a win32 project with CStrings (console application), and I noticed something odd when I want to pass to a function (like `strtok_s` for example) a `LPSTR` pointer from a `CString` with the method `GetBuffer()`, this last one instead of giving me a `LPSTR`, it gave me a `LPWSTR` (a pointer to a wide string)... `CString` is supposed to store 8 bit chars isn't it ?

I'm obliged in some cases to use `CStringA` for example to be able for example to use the method `Find()` because with a `CString` my input string must be a wide one. But in other another project (windowed program), I don't have this problem, i'm suspecting the headers (when I use afxstr.h "Find" works with a normal string, but not with afxcoll.h...)

Usually I work with `std::string` that's why I'm lost.

Comment: IIRC if your project targets Unicode `CString` will have internal buffers of type `LPWSTR`

Comment: Read in MSDN about CString https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: @demonplus: That document is for the MFC version that shipped with Visual Studio 6 (in 1998). Things have changed, the document is no longer true, since the merge of ATL and MFC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CString` is a typdef, declared as (*afxstr.h*):

```
typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC< TCHAR > > CString;
// Or, when using the MFC DLL
typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC_DLL< TCHAR > > CString;
```

Depending on what `TCHAR` is, a `CString` stores either an ANSI (MBCS) or Unicode string. There are also explicit instantiations of the `CStringT` template: `CStringW` and `CStringA`.

Either type has a conversion constructor, taking a constant pointer to the respective other character encoding. In other words: You can construct a `CStringW` from an ANSI (MBCS) string, as well as a `CStringA` from a UTF-16LE-encoded Unicode string.

If you need to be explicit about the character encoding, use either `CStringW` or `CStringA`.

---

Full documentation for `CString` is available at [CStringT Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx).